# find -exec grep 'string' result different from grep -r command's result

Tags: grep, find

Why does this command

```
find /etc -exec grep student {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

show me more results
than this command

```
grep -r student /etc 2>/dev/null
```

[image: terminal window]

Comment: Add `-H` to the `grep` command in the `find` run string: this will show you the file names, and thereby give you a better idea of what is happening, whether more files are found, or more matches in each file. It looks as though the `find` command is finding a dictionary, not found by `grep -r`.

Comment: Thank you AFH for the -H explanation will definitely use it in the future. 

Thank you Kamil, -R instead of -r has solved the problem. Nope my grep wasn't an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are some symbolic links under your `/etc`. It looks like your `grep -r` doesn't follow them but `find` does.

Try `grep -R`.

Note: neither `-r` nor `-R` is required by POSIX. Some implementations of `grep` may not support them; some may support one of them, not necessarily following (or not) symbolic links like in this example; some may treat `-R` and `-r` alike. Refer to `man 1 grep` in your OS to be sure.

Comment: I was puzzled why `find` with its default `-P` was returning links, but I now realise that that is precisely what it does: it returns a link, but this is passed to `grep`, which follows the link when reading the file, whereas `grep -r` ignores links, whether to files or directories. Both commands will return the same search results if `-type f` is added to the `find` run string. This may be obvious, but it took me some time to understand, so I thought it worth noting. Also, note that, if there are directory links, `grep -R` will check more files than the `find` command unless `-L` is added.